# Need to override the core file in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to override this core file because of real path issue

```
magento230\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php
```

Can you suggest how can we override this `isPathInDirectories`function in this file

Comment: Have you tried the preference in di.xml?

Comment: why do you need to override the method  `isPathInDirectoriesfunction`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php` Using preference

Just add below code to your **di.xml** file

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator" type="[VENDOR]\[EXTENSION]\View\Element\Template\File\Validator" />
```

now create the class `[VENDOR]\[EXTENSION]\View\Element\Template\File\Validator` that extends `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator`

This is done.

Answer (score 1):

I have made the two files for that (I have overridden this core file)

di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator" type="Custome\Customelink\Block\Validator" />
</config>
```

Validator.php file

```
namespace Custome\Customelink\Block;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File as FileDriver;

//use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File;
class Validator extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator
{
    protected $filePath;

    protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
    {
        //my codes
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override any of the core file of Magento2 by creating a **di.xml** file in your **module/etc** folder.

Here you can find some useful details as per your requirement.

[Custom Link](https://belvg.com/blog/overriding-layout-files-in-magento-2.html)

[Magento link](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-use-plugin-preference-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-magento-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use plugin(Interceptors) instead of override whole class.

please read magento 2 dev docs for more information

[Dev Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)